# clearInterval if pagination page is bigger than 1

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i'm working on small project using **Vue.js** i have created a pagination system to display my database users in a table, i have a small issue, i would like to know how can i stop the **setinterval** if my **getResult** function **page** variable is bigger than 1.
this is my code :

```
data(){
     return {
        editMode : true,
        customer_id : null,
        laravelData : {},
        formFields : {}
     }
  },
  methods:{
     getResults(page = 1){
        axios.get('Thirdparty/loadCustomers/' + page).then(response => {
           this.laravelData = response.data;
            });
     }
  },
  created(){
     self = this;
     setInterval(function(){
        self.getResults();
     }, 5000);
  }
```

Comment: I don’t see in your code where `page` will ever be greater than 1. Can you demonstrate at which point this could happen?

Comment: i'm looking for any way to stop the interval, because when i click on page 2 or 3 button of my pagination system i get the correct result of the page in question. 
but the interval function call the getResult without staying in the current page

Comment: Any `setInterval` without capturing the interval identifier is a red flag: at the _very_ least, have `currentInterval = setInterval(...)` and use `clearInterval(currentInterval)` when you need to stop things.

Comment: can i have an example code please, since i have already tried this way 
thank you

Comment: If you already tried that, please [talk about, and show, what you tried](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans can you double check my bottom answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, always capture identifiers from `setInterval` and `setTimeout`.

By capturing your interval ID you can later remove it from within your callback when the page value is larger than its default (1).

**EDIT**: The OP would like to be able to reset the interval when page resets.

```
created() {
  this.resetInterval();
},
methods: {
  resetInterval() {
    this.currentInterval && clearInterval(this.currentInterval);
    this.currentInterval = setInterval(() => this.getResults(), 5000);
  },
  getResults(page = 1) {
    if (page == 1 && !this.currentInterval) {
      this.resetInterval();
    } else {
      clearInterval(this.currentInterval);
    }
    axios.get('Thirdparty/loadCustomers/' + page).then(response => {
      this.laravelData = response.data;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works fine, i have just a small issue this time, when i come back to the page 1 the setinterval doesn't work again

Comment: I've updated the code to demonstrate the ability to reset the interval the returning to page 1. Hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't work, when i click on page two, page refresh automaticly and come back to page 1

Answer (score 0):

```
data(){
     return {
        editMode : true,
        customer_id : null,
        laravelData : {},
        formFields : {},
        currentInterval : null
     }
  },
  methods:{
     getResults(page = 1){
        clearInterval(this.currentInterval);
        axios.get('Thirdparty/loadCustomers/' + page).then(response => {
           this.laravelData = response.data;
            });
  },
  created(){
      self = this;
      self.currentInterval = setInterval(function(){
      self.getResults();
 }, 5000);
}
```